# KSTokenView change background and charackters

Tags: ios, swift, kstokenview

I am using KSTokenView library and I want change background color of ksTokenView which I couldn't find on library. Also after typing .(dot) it automatically takes as ksToken and I can't fill it as email.

Here is the [library](https://github.com/khawars/KSTokenView).

Comment: How you are adding KSTokenView library with pod or add in project ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `Programmatically.swift` for working example on change background color.
https://github.com/khawars/KSTokenView/blob/master/Examples/Examples/ViewControllers/Programmatically.swift

You would need to change `tokenBackgroundColor` property of `KSToken` object. Here is sample source code from above example link:

```
@IBAction func addToken(sender: AnyObject) {
        let title = names[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(names.count)))] as String
        let token = KSToken(title: title, object: title as AnyObject?)

        // Token background color
        var red = CGFloat(Float(arc4random()) / Float(UINT32_MAX))
        var green = CGFloat(Float(arc4random()) / Float(UINT32_MAX))
        var blue = CGFloat(Float(arc4random()) / Float(UINT32_MAX))
        token.tokenBackgroundColor = UIColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: 1.0)

        // Token text color
        red = CGFloat(Float(arc4random()) / Float(UINT32_MAX))
        green = CGFloat(Float(arc4random()) / Float(UINT32_MAX))
        blue = CGFloat(Float(arc4random()) / Float(UINT32_MAX))
        token.tokenTextColor = UIColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: 1.0)

        tokenView.addToken(token)
    }
```

To avoid creating a token when you type a dot (.), change property `tokenizingCharacters`. Currently, it creates a token automatically, if you type a dot or a comma. Check here:
https://github.com/khawars/KSTokenView/blob/master/KSTokenView/KSTokenView.swift

```
 /// An array of string values. Default values are "." and ",". Token is created with typed text, when user press any of the character mentioned in this Array
   open var tokenizingCharacters = [".", ","]
```

So you can remove characters to avoid create token. Like this:

```
tokenView.tokenizingCharacters = [];
```